# Cannot find LICENSE.txt during install

Tags: homebrew

I am developing a formula that uses a CMake step to generate build files. During this I encounter the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.4/share/cmake/Modules/CPack.cmake:441 (message):
  CPack license resource file: "/tmp/myformula-20180615-53709-m1sfii/LICENSE.txt"
  could not be found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.4/share/cmake/Modules/CPack.cmake:446 (cpack_check_file_exists)
  CMakeModules/installer.cmake:49 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:219 (include)
```

I checked the temporary directory to see that LICENSE.txt is in fact missing. Browsing the brew source code I saw that brew considers this a [Metafile](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/af9ddfe899c3593a4d8168d4ade61eccd01d19b0/Library/Homebrew/metafiles.rb). Is it filtered out? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I think CPack is just looking for a licence.txt, that is provided by yourself.

So either:

1. You can create a license file and use:

   ```
   set (CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE  
       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/License.txt")
   ```

Where you, of course, need to set `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, or just hardcode for your preferred folder for while testing.

2. If you don't care of license, just don't set `CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE`. Packing shall be successful with a license warning.

Comment: I want to create a Homebrew formula for a library, preferably without editing the build files of said library. The source already contains the LICENSE.txt file, however Homebrew filters it when copying the sources to its temporary build path. Ideally, I want to prevent this from happening.